# gpg: malformed GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable Could not sign jar

Tags: clojure, leiningen, gnupg

I'm trying to `lein deploy clojars` on macos with the latest gpgtools installed, and I get

```
gpg: malformed GPG_AGENT_INFO environment variable
Could not sign jar
```

I've tried manually starting gpg-agent and setting GPG_AGENT_INFO but no luck

Comment: This question is well suited to this site and tag, though we need a little more information to help. What version of leiningen are you building your project with (and are you using that same version to push it) and what version of gpg do you have installed. does gpg otherwise "work" for you (can you encrypt a message to yourself and then decrypt it)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had an older version of gpg-agent installed via macports. Uninstall that, and install the latest gpg-tools (MacGPG2 2.0.30) and it works.

Answer (score -1):

Removing gnupg1 and installing gnupg2 package from macports helped.
gnupg2 package in macports as for the time of writing is up to date. The issue was probably gnupg1 being installed as a default some time ago.

Comment: Can you improve your answer by explaining how your code resolves the problem?